# Bad pyplot.table resolution

Tags: python, resolution, matplotlib-table

Kind of newbie in Python...
I am doing some estimations on Python and I want to plot as tables the results.
My problem is that the plot i get is very small, so if i scale it look like cr@p because of resolution.

Here is the code i use: (not so delicate, I am still experimenting)

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(3,2)
ax[0,0].axis('tight')
ax[0,0].axis('off')
ax[0,0].title.set_text('μ_1')
the_table = ax[0,0].table(cellText=mu_1[0],loc='center')
ax[1,0].axis('tight')
ax[1,0].axis('off')
ax[1,0].title.set_text('μ_2')
the_table = ax[1,0].table(cellText=mu_1[1], loc='center')
ax[2,0].axis('tight')
ax[2,0].axis('off')
ax[2,0].title.set_text('μ_3')
the_table = ax[2,0].table(cellText=mu_1[2], loc='center')

ax[0,1].axis('tight')
ax[0,1].axis('off')
ax[0,1].title.set_text('Σ_1')
the_table = ax[0,1].table(cellText=Sigma_1[0], loc='center')
ax[1,1].axis('tight')
ax[1,1].axis('off')
ax[1,1].title.set_text('Σ_2')
the_table = ax[1,1].table(cellText=Sigma_1[1], loc='center')
ax[2,1].axis('tight')
ax[2,1].axis('off')
ax[2,1].title.set_text('Σ_3')
the_table.set_fontsize(20)
the_table = ax[2,1].table(cellText=Sigma_1[2], loc='center')
```

and here is the result: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoMWN.png)

Ideally I would like something like this [ideal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EOmc.png), a TeX output, but i don't know if its even possible,so if anyone has any info about it please enlight me!

Could somebody please help me on the resolution matter?

Thanks!!!